# Can you define a countable set containing undefinable elements?

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

Is it possible to construct a countable set that contains an undefinable set as an element?

Consider a set $X$ to be definable if there exists a parameter-free formula $\varphi$ in the language of ZFC $\{ \in \}$ such that $X$ as a class is equal to $\{ x : \varphi(x) \}$. Note that we are working with the class of all sets, not a model of ZFC.

Note that there must not exist a definable bijection with the natural numbers, or any element can be defined using the bijection.

Comment: What signature for the reals are we using? Is the set definable with or without parameters? Also ... the natural numbers are not definable in the reals. If they were then the integers would be definable in the reals, which [does not hold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19840/how-do-we-recognize-an-integer-inside-the-rationals#:~:text=It%20follows%20that%20neither%20the,in%20the%20real%20ordered%20field.).

Comment: @GregNisbet You might need to help me out here, because I'm not too confident in my knowledge on the field of mathematical logic. I was under the impression that it makes sense to talk about definable real numbers in first-order logic with ZF axioms. The axioms of specification, pairing, union, replacement, infinity, and power set should all give rise to definitions, which can be used to define the set of real numbers, for example with the Dedekind cut.

Comment: There are still a few ways to interpret your question. Is the vocabulary that you want for your sentence something like $(0, 1, +, -, *, <)$ that reflects the ordered field structure of the reals or $(\in)$ for set theory? For set theory you have to be *really* careful. If you're working with a model of set theory (which is itself a set) then cardinality inside the model and cardinality outside the model are different, see e.g. [Skolem's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox). So, you need to pick a signature. Please also define a definable set and a definable element.

Comment: @GregNisbet Can't we just define definability inductively with the axioms of specification, pairing, union, replacement, infinity and power set? For specification and replacement, we require the formula to be of first order logic. Then this is a second order recursive definition of definability in first order. I guess Skolem's paradox states that there are countably many definable sets, which may be weird since there are uncountable sets, but is not a contradiction. Ultimately, this was just a shower thought, so if you find it interesting, maybe you can provide a sensible interpretation?

Comment: I would suggest something like: "let definable mean definable without parameters in the language of ZFC $\in$. Note that we're working with true ZFC here, not a model of ZFC. If we're working with the true $\mathbb{R}$, constructed as Dedekind cuts, then by a cardinality argument some of the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are undefinable. Is it possible to construct a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains at least one undefinable real, but is itself definable?"

Comment: I don't want to just edit your question because there's no process for you to approve it or not, but feel free to use some or all of the language in the comment to modify the question. I suspect this question will likely be closed because it has 4 votes now out of 5, but it can be reopened afterwards. I don't actually know the answer to your set-theory flavored question. This is a bit different from uses of "definability" that I've seen before.

Comment: @GregNisbet Thank you for the suggestion, I will edit the question. Just a couple questions. You reworded the question to "Is it possible to construct a countable subset..." Is this different from "Does there exist a definable countable subset..."? Constructions and definitions seem closely related at least. Also, I'm thinking of removing the real numbers from the equation, just asking if a countable set can be constructed with undefinable elements. Might make the question less confusing.

Comment: I didn't intend "can you construct" to be meaningfully different from "does there exist". I just wanted to emphasize that an explicit example set would be nice. You could remove the real numbers ... in which case you are asking for a countable 0-definable set that contains an element that isn't 0-definable, with 0-definable meaning definable without parameters.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "true ZFC".  It does not make sense to talk about undefinable elements unless you are talking about some specific model.

Comment: @EricWofsey I meant sets (corresponding to set-sized classes?) definable by a formula without parameters in the class of all sets. I’m thinking of this class as a class-sized analogue of a model. I thought that was a coherent idea and it seems to be the author’s intent based on their earlier comments. I don’t know a way to reformulate the question using a model of set theory because I don’t know how cardinality works exactly in that setting. Is there a way to reformulate the question and refer to a specific model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definability is a very sensitive subject, first of all, note that Tarski's undefinability of the truth tells us that the question "is $X$ undefinable" is not actually a well formed question (*but note that saying* "$X$ is definable by $φ$" *is well formed*).

When working with definable objects you need to restrict yourself to set-models to be able to talk about this kind of questions, a variation of your question can be:

> Assuming $Con(ZFC)$, Is it possible that there exists a model $(N,ε)⊨ZFC$ such there exists an (internally) countable set $a\in N$ such that for every $φ$ such that $(N,ε)⊨φ(a)$ implies that there exists $a\ne b\in N$ such that $(N, ε)⊨φ(b)$?

Or the stronger

> Assuming $Con(ZFC)$, Is it *provable* that there exists a model $(N,ε)⊨ZFC$ such there exists an (internally) countable set $a\in N$ such that for every $φ$ such that $(N,ε)⊨φ(a)$ implies that there exists $a\ne b\in N$ such that $(N, ε)⊨φ(b)$?

Turns out the answer is "yes" but it is boring, take a model $(N,ε)$ with uncountably many countable sets (**note** here I mean that *externally* there are uncountable many sets that are *internally* countable), we know that there exists only countably many formulaes without parameters, so at least one countable set is undefinable (note that this argument fails in $V$ not because there are somehow more formulaes, but because the question is simply not first order expressable).

A less boring variation will be the dual, *is it possible for this property to fail*?

> Assuming $Con(ZFC)$, Is it possible that there exists a model $(M,ε)⊨ZFC$ such that for every $a\in M$ there exists a formula $φ$ without parameters such that $(M,ε)⊨φ(x)$ if and only if $x=a$?

(note that I removed the condition that $a$ is countable, this is a bit stronger statement than the actual dual)

Or the stronger dual variation, *is it provable that this property fails for some model*?

> Assuming $Con(ZFC)$, Is it provable that there exists a model $(M,ε)⊨ZFC$ such that for every $a\in M$ there exists a formula $φ$ without parameters such that $(M,ε)⊨φ(x)$ if and only if $x=a$?

Turns out that the duals variations are also true, Myhill has proven that if ZFC is consistence than there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ "pointwise-definable" models of ZFC (pointwise definable is the property I stated in the dual variations).

---

Proof of the strong dual form:

Let $\mathscr M=(M,ε)$ be any model of ZFC, we may assume $\mathscr M$ is also a model of $V=HOD$. Models of $ZFC+V=HOD$ are exactly those who have definable (without parameters) well ordering $φ(x,y)$, for each formula $ψ(x;y)$, one has a definable Skolem function $f_ψ(y)=\min_φ(ψ(x,y))$, but then the set $N\subseteq M$ consistent of the definable sets of $\mathscr M$ is it's own Skolem Hull of the set of definable Skolem functions, hence $\mathscr N=(N,ε)\prec \mathscr M$.

So $\mathscr N\models ZFC+V=HOD$ and agree with $\mathscr M$ about what is definable, hence every set in $N$ is definable without parameters by $\mathscr N$. $\square$